# DATAGRIP SQL editor doesn't erase statements after being executed

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

I have a bit of a problem with my DATAGRIP SQL IDE.

When i run any type of a statement, for example, lets say, SHOW DATABASES; in the lower part of the IDE - the console, i get the query results, but in the upper part of the IDE where i write the code, the code stays. When i do this in a terminal shell, when i execute the statement, the statement dissapears and i get results. Here i get results, but the statement stays up there in the editor and in order to do another statement, i need to manualy erese it in order to write a new one?

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Every ide does this, because you usually have a complex query that need to be refined. if you that picky close the query tab and opne a new one.

Comment: how can i open a new one? after every statement?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke *File -> New -> Query Console*. 
In case you need to get multiple result sets - select all of them and execute.